An error occurred when using DBeaver to connect to PieCloudDB
I am trying to connect PieCloudDB Database with the DBeaver client , but when I execute SQL, an error occurs: prepared statement "stmtcache_XX" does not exist. I don't know what happened, and I don't know how to troubleshoot. Any suggestion on this?

Check whether the connection mode used is “Transaction mode” and whether PreparedStatement syntax is used. PieCloudDB Database Transaction mode does not support Prepared Statement and Session-level configuration settings. It is recommended to switch to Session mode and try again.
